Vue project deployed on nginx, 404 after refreshing the page
image1
image2
The image below shows the situation after refreshing.
image3
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        # 默认页面
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


        # alias提供静态文件服务。前端配置
        location /project1/ {
            # configure 1. work but 404 after refreshing browser
            alias D:/DevelopingEnvironments/nginx-1.26.1/html/project1/;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

            # configure 2. work but 404 after refreshing browser
            # alias D:/DevelopingEnvironments/nginx-1.26.1/html/project1/;
            # index index.html index.htm;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /project1/index.html;

            # configure 3. work but 404 after refreshing browser
            # root D:/DevelopingEnvironments/nginx-1.26.1/html/project1/;
            # index index.html index.htm;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

            # configure 4. work but 404 after refreshing browser
            # root D:/DevelopingEnvironments/nginx-1.26.1/html/project1/;
            # index index.html index.htm;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /project1/index.html;

            # configure 5. work but 404 after refreshing browser
            # root /html/project1/;
            # index index.html index.htm;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /project1/index.html;

        }

        # proxy_pass用于反向代理。后端配置
        location /prod-api/ {
            # gateway
            proxy_pass http://192.168.10.201:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

    }

Can somebody help me out with something, I'm so puzzled. See the question details. There are 5 methods that I have tried. Thank you very much for your answers, and I would like to best-wish you.
After refreshing, I press the F12 and console show me this information. should I configure it into nginx? I don't think so.
image4

Honestly use Netlify or Cloudflare pages. You'll have a better experience, will be faster and done in a minute.

@kissu，sorry，I have no enough reputations so I just give the image link out.

How is it related to my previous comment?
